# loading data into dimension date table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

Well I have a dimension date table which has two attributes Month and Year like it's written in the script, and the month (mois) is my primary key. And I have a different year with the same month like in the source file show. So what should 
I do? take them all or should I use distinct?

My source file is excel plus. I have data (ord-date) from table sales that I need to get from database pubs.

PS: I'm using ssis (visual studio)

*This is my source date*

[image: this is my source date]

*This is how I create my dimension date table cause our professor told us to create it like (no need to the details)*

[image: query]

*I know how to import data from excel and I split the date. I only have from is when I load to the dimension table I found a problem. My problem is I have for example 2 dates (month and year only) 05/1995 and 05/1995 and I want to load them into my dimension table but I can't have my month as my primary key . And primary key should be unique*

Comment: This is unclear, what is your goal , which report or analysis you want to build? your question is depending on your goal.

Comment: @hadi i want to build data warehouse .

Comment: you have to show what have you tried. if you don't show any efforts no one will helps you at stackoverflow to do homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to add a `DataFlow Task` that contains an `Excel Source` -> `Script Component` - > 2x `OLEDB Destination`
- In the script component you have to add a New Output `Dim Date` with 2 Columns `Month` and `Year` , and set the `Synchronous Input` property to `none`.

[image]

- The First Output will contains the columns containing the other data and it is synchronous to the Input buffer.
- In the script you have to create a list that store distinct months and every time a new month is found it will generate a `Dim Date` output.

your script should look like.

```
Dim lstDates As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

Public Overrides Sub Input0Buffer_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)  


        If Not Row.Date_IsNull Then

            Dim strMonth As String = Row.Date.ToString("MM/yyyy")

            If Not lstDates.Contains(strMonth) Then

                With DimDateBuffer
                    .AddRow()
                    .Month = strMonth
                    .Year = Right(strMonth, 4)
                End With

                lstDates.Add(strMonth)

            End If 

        End If 
End Sub
```

*That way you will have no duplicate in Dimension table, also if this package should run periodically you can add an `Execute SQL Task` that get all dimensions from data warehouse and load them into the list created in the script component using an `Object` variable*

- Finally map the `DimDate` output columns to the First `OLEDB destination` and the First Output columns to the other destination

Comment: No I'm not trying to create date dimension i already have it. I'm trying to load data into it !

Comment: You question is unclear!! Please edit it and be more specific. also Specify data source type

Comment: Also the way you created date dimension is not correct.

Comment: @SirinàStrong i can't give you a detailed answer if not showing any efforts, all i have done is to provide you useful links to achieve that.

Comment: @SirinàStrong and also i am happy to help when you start building this package. we all was there. good luck

Comment: i know how to import data from excel and i split the date. I only have from is when i load to the dimension table i found a problem. My problem is i have for example 2 dates (month and year only) 05/1995 and 05/1995 and i want to load them into my dimension table but i can't i have my month my primary key . And primary key should be unique !!!

Comment: @SirinàStrong now its ok. Give me a moment and i will provide you a solution. :)

Comment: it's okat, take your time sorry i last comment i meant 05/1995 and 05/1996

Comment: @SirinàStrong i edited my answer. and updated + upvoted your question. good luck

Comment: Okaaay i will try it

Comment: @SirinàStrong i m still waiting . If it worked u have to accept or upvote this answer. Else give a reply

Comment: @SirinàStrong if it worked u have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)